# How to calculate eigenvectors of a covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, covariance

I want, if possible through examples, explanations about how to calculate eigenvectors of a covariance matrix,

THanks

Comment: @ites What exactly do you mean by "how to calculate" the eigenvectors? Are you trying to calculate the eigenvectors by hand (using a paper or pencil) or are you trying to program a computer to calculate these eigenvectors?

Comment: i am trying by hand

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Direct_calculation) for some methods that can done by hand for simple matrices. While the methods start with a discussion of finding the eigenvalues, most of them include a discussion of the eigenvectors as well.

Comment: it is not helping sry i need a full answer instead not from Wikipedia